# How to Create radio button group to the form to allow the selection of the smoking/non-smoking section of the restaurant?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I wish to emulate the behaviour of radio buttons withing a bootstrap `form-group` so a line in a form has several buttons ("btn btn-success" for example), with the buttons being able to be "selected", but only one of them can be selected at a given moment.
I want a Output like this:

[image]

But I am getting this:

[image]

Also I am not able to select the Smoking button

The Code for the Following is :

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="section" class="col-12 col-md-2">Section</label>
       <div class="col-md-10">
         <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-success active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>Non- 
               Smoking
            </label>
          <label class="btn btn-danger">
             <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">Smoking
          </label>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `btn-group-toggle`to your `btn-group` div will solve the issue.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="section" class="col-12 col-md-2">Section</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-success active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>Non- 
               Smoking
            </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger">
             <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">Smoking
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
input[type="radio"] {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/auo9Ly54/

remove **autocomplete="off"** **checked** in:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>
```